# What does "pimpier" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, idioms, phrases

In Neal Brennan's stand up comedy show:

> Neal Brennan: "How many of you believe, by round of applause, that men actually wanna get married? And yet you force us to do it... without shame or regret and the **pimpier** shit you do is you convince us it's our idea..."

What does "pimpier" mean? It should mean "worse" by the translated subtitle but I can't find it in dictionary, the meaning of "pimpy" doesn't seem fit here. Why does it mean "worse"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can tell "pimpier" is a form of *pimp* (pimpier → pimpy → pimp). I would say this usage is uncommon and/or unusual, and so it is difficult to give a precise definition.  In this case, I would say the meaning is closer to *impressive*, *skillful*, *remarkable*, etc.

> pimp
>
> A pimp is someone who employs prostitutes — they work for the pimp, who gets a cut of their money. He pimps them.
>
> Pimp is a word that has greatly shifted in meaning, as it sometimes means "great" or "cool," as in "That bike is pimp!" However, that's a slang meaning that many people, especially adults, won't understand or like. The main meaning of pimp as the boss of prostitutes is pretty creepy, because prostitution is illegal and pimps are not known for treating their workers very nicely. For some reason, pimps are known for their flashy dress.
>
> ([Vocaublary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/pimp))
>
> ---
>
> pimp
> verb
>
> 2 informal with object Make (something) more showy or impressive.
> *‘he pimped up the car with spoilers and twin-spoke 18-inch alloys’*
>
> ([Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/pimp))

As suggested above, *pimp* can be used to say something is *cool*, *outstanding*, *impressive*, *excellent*, *remarkable*. etc. As I mentioned before, "pimpier" (or "pimpy") is a bit unusual, but we can still rephrase it as something like

> And yet you force us to do it... without shame or regret and the ***more remarkable*** shit you do is you convince us it's our idea...

I can't tell you why they translated it as *worse*. For the purpose of this joke, it is *worse* from the perspective of the comedian (or men). But I would have chosen a different translation.

It is not uncommon for comedians to use words in usual ways for comedic effect. This is true of colloquial speech as well.

Comment: ‘Remarkable’ is a good word there, because it can have a negative or positive meaning.